# does node have a place to put custom console methods like ~/.irbrc?

Tags: node.js

I was thinking it would be handy if I could `reload!` code in the Node console, something to the effect of:

`reload('./path/to/my/file.js')`

that would delete the code from the cache then load it again -- handy for exercising prototype code. Seemed like a natural function to place in node's equivalent of `~/.irbrc`. But I can't find that. Does node have such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know there's such a tool. But I believe what you need can be achieved by using [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

Use `sudo npm install nodemon -g` to install it. Then launch your application by `nodemon app.js` instead of `node app.js`. Then it watches for changes to nearby `.js` files, and automatically restart when you save.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that or use a test runner. Neither one really helps me at the console though.